# Error "uninitialized classifier or invalid context" in tensoflow app demo

Tags: android, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I build and run tensoflow app demo from:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo

I replace model "`mobilenet_quant_v1_224.tflite`" by my custom model "`optimized_graph.tflite`" and label "`labels.txt`" by my custom label "`retrained_labels.txt`".

App run ok but i receive a error:

> uninitialized classifier or invalid context in tensoflow app
>   demo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. To be precise my console gave the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
>       Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 5603
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 196608 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 602112 bytes.

I had trained my model for an image size of 128 and not 224px. Thus when I ran my model in my computer I would have to specify the image height and width as 128. So after I got the error, I figured out that I had to set the image size at 128 in `ImageClassifier.java`

```
static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 128;
static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 128;
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of related issues on Github (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18658, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15751).

You probably need to update https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/BUILD to include your custom model and labels files.